# Pygame window not opening, but pygame icon showing up in doc

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to figure out why my display is not showing up. I am on a mac and I can see the pygame icon in my dock showing up, but there are no windows being made. I am running pygame 2.0.2 on python 3.9.6 on pycharm. I've tried opening other pygame scripts and they open fine, but I don't see any difference between how the 2 scripts open it.

```
import pygame
import random
from enum import Enum
from collections import namedtuple

pygame.init()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (200, 0, 0)
GREEN1 = (0, 255, 0)
GREEN2 = (0, 200, 100)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
SPEED = 20
BLOCK_SIZE = 20

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x, y')
font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 25)


class Direction(Enum):
    RIGHT = 1
    LEFT = 2
    UP = 3
    DOWN = 4


class SnakeGame:
    def __init__(self, w=640, h=480):
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        # init display
        self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((self.w, self.h))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        # init game state
        self.direction = Direction.RIGHT

        self.head = Point(self.w / 2, self.h / 2)
        self.snake = [self.head,
                      Point(self.head.x - BLOCK_SIZE, self.head.y),
                      Point(self.head.x - BLOCK_SIZE * 2, self.head.y)]
        self.score = 0
        self.food = None
        self._place_food()

    def _place_food(self):
        x = random.randint(0, (self.w - BLOCK_SIZE) // BLOCK_SIZE) * BLOCK_SIZE
        y = random.randint(0, (self.w - BLOCK_SIZE) // BLOCK_SIZE) * BLOCK_SIZE
        self.food = Point(x, y)
        if self.food in self.snake:
            self._place_food()

    def play_step(self):
        # Collect user input

        # Move

        # Check if game over

        # Place new food or just move

        # Update ui and clock
        # self._update_ui()
        # self.clock.tick(SPEED)
        # Return game over and score
        game_over = False
        return game_over, self.score

    def _update_ui(self):
        self.display.fill(BLACK)

        for pt in self.snake:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.display, GREEN1, pygame.Rect(pt.x, pt.y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE))
            pygame.draw.rect(self.display, GREEN2, pygame.Rect(pt.x + 4, pt.y + 4, 12, 12))

        pygame.draw.rect(self.display, RED, pygame.Rect(self.food.x, self.food.y, BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE))
        text = font.render('Score: ' + str(self.score), True, WHITE)
        self.display.blit(text, [0, 0])
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = SnakeGame()

    while True:
        game_over, score = game.play_step()
        if game_over:
            break

    print('Final Score', score)


    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to handle the events in the application loop. See [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) respectively [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump):

> For each frame of your game, you will need to make some sort of call to the event queue. This ensures your program can internally interact with the rest of the operating system.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = SnakeGame()

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False 

        game_over, score = game.play_step()
        if game_over:
            break

    print('Final Score', score)
    pygame.quit()
```